# Second Order diff equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Find all solutions to the differential equation:

$4y''+\beta^2 y = cos \beta x$

Where $\beta$ is a positive constant.

Starting with the homogeneous part :

$4r^2+\beta^2=0$

$r = \frac{i\beta}{2}$ since we only want the positive root.

Giving the solution:

$C_1\cos(\frac{\beta x}{2})+C_2\sin(\frac{\beta x}{2})$

Is this the correct way to start off? How would you find $y_p$?

Comment: To find $y_p$ there are two popular methods:  "Undetermined coefficients" and "variation of parameters".  I assume you are expected to use the method explained just before this in the book or lectures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$4r^2+\beta^2=0$$
Note that:
$$4r^2-i^2\beta^2=0$$
$$(2r-i\beta)(2r+i\beta)=0$$
$$\implies r= \pm i\dfrac {\beta}{2}$$
This line in your attempt is correct:
$$y=C_1\cos(\frac{\beta x}{2})+C_2\sin(\frac{\beta x}{2})$$
For the particular solution:
$$4y''+\beta^2 y = \cos \beta x$$
Try:
$$y_p =A \cos (\beta x)$$

Comment: $y_p=A\cos(\beta x)$
$y_p'=-A\sin(\beta x)*\beta$
$y_p''=-A\cos(\beta x)*\beta^2$
And when plugging into the equation i get A =$ \frac{-1}{3\beta^2} $

Comment: @Schwep  $y_p'=-A \beta \sin (\beta x)$ Looks good yeah

Comment: The A you find is correct now you have the particular solution add it to the homogeneous solution. @Schwep $y=y_h+y_p$

Comment: So the final solution would be $y = C_1\cos(\frac{\beta x}{2})+C_2\sin(\frac{\beta x}{2}) - \frac{1}{3\beta^2}*(cos(\beta x)$?

Comment: add the cosine function to the coefficent A @Schwep and dont forget the factor 2 inside the sine and cosine function

Comment: $y=C_1\cos(\beta x/2)+C_2\sin(\beta x/2) - \frac{1}{3\beta^2}\cos (\beta x)$

Comment: Perfect, thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: Dont forget the factor 2 in the sine and cosine function. @Schwep you are very welcome

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track. You can search for a particular solution "similar" to the RHS. In this case, you should try something of the form $y_p(x)=k_1 \sin (\beta x) + k_2 \cos(\beta x)=$, and compute $k_1, k_2$ such that it is actually a solution. You'll see that $k_1=0$ and $k_2 = \frac{1}{3 \beta^2}$.

Comment: So $y_p(x)$ would be: 

$y_p = k_1\sin(\beta x) + k_2cos(\beta x)$
$y_p'=k_1\cos(\beta x) * \beta - k_2\sin(\beta x) * \beta$
$y_p''=-k_1\sin(\beta x) *\beta^2 - k_2\cos(\beta x) * \beta^2$

And plugging into the equation gives $k_1 =0$ and $k_2 = \frac{1}{3 \beta^2}$?

Comment: @Schwep yes, that is it. You just need to make the coefficients match (at this point we are  using the fact that $\cos(\beta x)$ and $\sin(\beta x)$ are linearly independent)